# Converting csv to json and wrap the json by another variable

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a csv data that looks like the following:

```
test_subject confidence_score
maths 0.41
english 0.51
```

I used pandas to create a json file using the following code.

```
tt1.to_json(orient = "records", lines = True)
```

The output of the above code is as follows:

```
{"test_subject":"maths","confidence_score":0.41}
{"test_subject":"english","confidence_score":0.51}
```

Now, I want to add source to all the rows like the following and may be backslash on all the variables as follows.

```
{"source":"{\"test_subject\":maths,\"confidence_score\":0.41}}
{"source":"{\"test_subject\":english,\"confidence_score\":0.51}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could use dictionary? Did you tried?

Comment: No, I haven't tried dictionary. Would you please suggest how to achieve this ?

Comment: Maybe?? https://regex101.com/r/g64mzx/2 - paste in, copy out.  Maybe. :o).  If it's a one time thing.

Comment: Actually this is not a one time thing. I would need to do this quite a lot on a weekly basis.

Comment: The example result you give, with the backslashes, aren't valid JSON... why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Note, the fastest, easiest way to do this is probably not to use pandas at all... which seems like a pointless use case here to begin with...

Comment: Are you trying to produce a json's lines file, where each line is a json object with a single key, `"source"` which has a value that is a *JSON string*, which iteself is a valid JSON?

Comment: My use case with this is I want to create the file in such a format that I can pass it to the Sagemaker GroundTruth API to create the tagging job. The format I provided works with the Sagemaker GroundTruth API.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex (could read/write from/to a file etc. if required), try:

```
import re

data = '''
{"test_subject":"maths","confidence_score":0.41}
{"test_subject":"english","confidence_score":0.51}
{"test_subject":"maths","confidence_score":0.41}
{"test_subject":"english","confidence_score":0.51}

'''

data2 = ''

for line in data.splitlines():
    data2 = data2 + re.sub(r'{\"(.*?)\":\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\":(.*?)}', r'{"source":"{\\"\1\\":\2,\\"\3\\":\4}}\n', line)
    
print(data2)

{"source":"{\"test_subject\":maths,\"confidence_score\":0.41}}
{"source":"{\"test_subject\":english,\"confidence_score\":0.51}}
{"source":"{\"test_subject\":maths,\"confidence_score\":0.41}}
{"source":"{\"test_subject\":english,\"confidence_score\":0.51}}
```

For writing to a file (example):

```
f = open("myFile.txt", "a")
for line in data.splitlines():
    f.writelines([re.sub(r'{\"(.*?)\":\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\":(.*?)}', r'{"source":"{\\"\1\\":\2,\\"\3\\":\4}}', line)])
f.close()
```

The regex used in `re.sub` is shown here: https://regex101.com/r/g64mzx/2.  If there is more than 'test_subject', 'maths', 'confidence_score', and a float, the regex would need to be updated to match the new string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will it scale if I have a bigger dataset ? This is just an example dataset and I have many fields.

Comment: Updated the answer (see last line).  The regex would need to change to match the right substrings.  Plenty of help on here if you post a question 'given string X how do I substitute it and make Y'.  This isn't a good solution if the dataset is always changing.